# How to evaluate this Kotlin function to convert ArrayList of Any? to ArrayList of Double

Tags: arrays, list, kotlin, converters

I made this function to convert an array list of Any? to an array list of Double, or to null. Am I missing any possible thing?

```
    fun toArrayListDoubleOrNull(arg: ArrayList<Any?>): ArrayList<Double>? {
        if (arg.isNullOrEmpty() || arg.contains(null)) {
            return null;
        }
        arg.forEach { i: Any? ->
            if (i.toString().trim().toDoubleOrNull() == null) {
                return null;
            }
        };
        val ret = ArrayList<Double>();
        arg.forEach { i: Any? -> ret.add(i.toString().trim().toDouble()); };
        return ret;
    }
```

Comment: Wait, what? Why?

Comment: You only want to return the double Array IF all values are not null and all values are doubles?

Comment: Markus.. Yes, this is exactly what I want to do.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your original use case could be solved in a better way, so maybe you want to share why this function is needed in the first place. Until this happens, you can do something like this:

```
fun List<Any?>.toDoubles(): List<Double>? =
    takeIf { isNotEmpty() && none { e -> e == null || e !is Double } }?.map { it as Double }
```

In action:

```
val allDouble = listOf<Any>(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)
val stuff = listOf("", 1, 2.0, 3.0)
val doublesAndNull = listOf<Any?>(1.0, null, 2.0)
println(allDouble.toDoubles()) //[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
println(stuff.toDoubles()) //null
println(doublesAndNull.toDoubles()) //null
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirements this is a bit more "idiomatic" approach:

```
fun toArrayListDoubleOrNull(input: ArrayList<Any?>): List<Double>? {
    val result = input
        .filter { it is Double }
        .map { it as Double }
    return if(result.size == input.size) {
        result
    } else {
        null
    }
}
```

**DISCLAIMER it now returns a List instead of an ArrayList**

To test it I wrote following Tests:

```
class ArrayListToDouble {

    @Test
    fun `toArrayListDoubleOrNull with null values`() {
        val input: ArrayList<Any?> = arrayListOf(12.0, 13.0, null)
        val doubleArrayList = stackoverflow.toArrayListDoubleOrNull(input)
        assertTrue(doubleArrayList == null)
    }

    @Test
    fun `toArrayListDoubleOrNull without null values`() {
        val input: ArrayList<Any?> = arrayListOf(12.0, 13.0)
        val output: List<Double> = stackoverflow.toArrayListDoubleOrNull(input)!!
        assertTrue(output == arrayListOf(12.0, 13.0))
    }

}
```

A bit more idiomatic would be using an extension function:

```
fun List<Any?>.toDoubleListOrNull(): List<Double>? {
    val result = this
        .filter { it is Double }
        .map { it as Double }
    return if(result.size == this.size) {
        result
    } else {
        null
    }
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
val input = arrayListOf(12.0, 15.2)
val output = input.toDoubleListOrNull()
```

Comment: I appreciate your intricate answer. I am not an expert programmer. I just program to help myself solve some accounting and business matters I face in daily life. I do not prefer extension functions because they distract me a little bit when calling them. That's why I uses a traditional fun approach